# How to change opacity for circles on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, windows, canvas, html5-canvas

So what I'm trying to do here is make multiple circles on my canvas and individually change the opacity of each of them. Here's what I tried so far, I know that I'm definitely putting the interval in the wrong place but I'm very confused as to how these canvases work exactly:

```
function makeCircle(x,y)
{
 canvas.beginPath();
 canvas.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
 color = generateRandomColor();
 canvas.fillStyle = color;
 canvas.fill();
 canvas.lineWidth = 0;
 canvas.strokeStyle = color;
 setInterval(function()
            { 
                if(canvas.globalAlpha>=.05)
                {
                    canvas.globalAlpha-=.05;
                    console.log("here");
                }
                else
                {
                    canvas.globalAlpha = 0;
                    console.log(canvas.globalAlpha);
                    clearInterval();
                }
            }, 2000)
 canvas.stroke();
}
```

Doing this does not change the opacity of the circles at all as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what you are trying to do with that nested setInterval, or why use it at all...

Here is what I would do:

```js
function makeCircle(x, y, color, alpha) {
  canvas.beginPath();
  canvas.globalAlpha = alpha
  canvas.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  canvas.fillStyle = color;
  canvas.fill();
}


var canvas_doc = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas = canvas_doc.getContext("2d");

makeCircle(20, 20, "red", 0.5)
makeCircle(30, 30, "blue", 0.5)
makeCircle(50, 50, "green", 0.9)

makeCircle(120, 20, "red", 1)
makeCircle(180, 30, "blue", 1)
makeCircle(150, 50, "green", 1)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Simple, right?
I just added a few more parameters to the function to pass the color and alpha.
Like that we can draw multiple color circles with ease.

---

You want to create some sort of animation using the globalAlpha...
We can use `setInterval` for that, here is an example:

```js
function makeCircle(x, y, color, alpha) {
  canvas.beginPath();
  canvas.globalAlpha = alpha
  canvas.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  canvas.fillStyle = color;
  canvas.fill();
}

var globalAlpha = 0.1
function draw() {
  globalAlpha += 0.02
  if (globalAlpha > 2) 
    globalAlpha = 0.1
    
  canvas.clearRect(0,0 , 999, 999)
  makeCircle(20, 20, "red", globalAlpha)
  makeCircle(30, 30, "blue", globalAlpha)
  makeCircle(50, 50, "green", globalAlpha)

  makeCircle(120, 20, "red", 1)
  makeCircle(130, 30, "blue", 1)
  makeCircle(150, 50, "green", 1)
}

var canvas_doc = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas = canvas_doc.getContext("2d");

setInterval(draw, 50)
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of things:

- your `canvas` variable is not the canvas, it's the context. Rename it to avoid confusion (`ctx` is generally used).
- `clearInterval` takes a parameter: a reference to the interval to clear. Put it in a variable, and use it.
- you're not drawing anything inside your interval. You need to do `ctx.fill()` inside of it.
- even with that change, you would only be drawing over the previously drawn circles (and not see any change). Once you drew something, the canvas is just a set of pixels. So if you want to retrieve part of what was behind the circle (by transparency), you need to clear your canvas and start over on every interval (redraw what was previously there before you added the circle). In the demo below, I save the image before drawing the first circle, and restore it on every iteration, but if other things are going on at the same time in your use case, you may actually want to redraw every element individually.

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
    ctx    = canvas.getContext("2d");

function makeCircle(x, y) {
  // Save the background
  var bg = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 20, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  color = '#f00'; // For the demo
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fill();
  var timer = setInterval(function() {
    // Clear the canvas
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    // Redraw the background
    ctx.putImageData(bg, 0, 0);
    if (ctx.globalAlpha >= .05) {
      ctx.globalAlpha -= .05;
      ctx.fill();
    } else {
      ctx.globalAlpha = 0;
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, 50);
}

ctx.fillRect(50, 50, 30, 100); // For the demo
makeCircle(50, 50);
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I think that nested setInterval is a horrible idea... if one creates a function `makeCircle(x,y)` educated guess is to reuse it and draw many circles at different locations... Add six makeCircle see what happens

Comment: @HelderSepulveda Yes you're right, that's why I added the bit about "if other things are going on at the same time". If only one circle is drawn at a given time, this will be sufficient, but otherwise, a common `draw` function which draws everything based on a global state as you did makes more sense. But even so, I think each circle should control its own "decay" (what if they are drawn on click, at different locations and different times ?). But this goes beyond the simple question that was asked. We'll see what the OP says :)